# will be returned from method understaning

Tags: android, remoteview

I'm reading a book "Android Application Development for dummies" and i can not understand that line of code can you explain it to me,please

```
RemoteViews updateViews=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget);
```

And here is how author explain it :
Here I am building a RemoteView object with the current package 
name as well as the layout that will be returned from this method. 
The layout, `R.layout.widget`, is shown in Listing 7-3.

But how to understand this "will be returned from this method"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specifying an XML layout file that is part of your app. Generally, RemoteViews are for widgets - so this is saying that the creation of this remote view will return the XML layout specified as R.layout.x, that you can then modify the contents of.

Comment: So,RemoteView goes for information to widget and then return to the program with this information and after that you can modify it,am i right?